# Check an annotation from a Field without isAnnotationPresent

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I need to check if there is an annotation present at a `Field`, but I can't use `isAnnotationPresent` to check it.

```
public void foo(Class<?> clazz) {
    Field[] fieldReflection = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field fieldReflect : fieldReflection){
        if (fieldReflect.isAnnotationPresent(FieldSize.class){
            //do something
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm doing today, there is another way to check if the `Field` have an annotation?

Comment: Why not?.............

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis just because i'm using TotalCross to build the final project, and it don't accept the command `isAnnotationPresent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found how to do..

Besides use `isAnnotationPresent`, I could check this way:

```
FieldSize annotation = fieldReflect.getAnnotation(FieldSize.class);
if (annotation != null) {
```

So the final code would be like:

```
public void foo(Class<?> clazz) {
    Field[] fieldReflection = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field fieldReflect : fieldReflection){
        FieldSize annotation = fieldReflect.getAnnotation(FieldSize.class);
        if (annotation != null){
            //do something
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```